# codeigniter to load view using ajax call expect success message

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How to login and show user profile in **codeigniter** load profile view using **ajax**

```
public function success() {
        $data = array(
            'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
            'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
        );
        $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            // $this->load->view('user_profile');
            echo 'login';
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
            $this->load->view('user/login', $data);
        }
    }
```

How to load user profile view in script expect login success message

```
         <script>
                    $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var uname = $('#uname').val();
                        var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
                        if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
                        {
                            $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
                        } else {
                            $('#errmessage').html("").hide();

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "<?= base_url();?>User_controller/success/",
                                data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                                   success: function (data) {
                                $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data);
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $('#successmessage').fadeOut("slow");
                                }, 2000);
                            }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

PHP:- return a json response with redirect url to ajax request.

```
public function success() {
    $data = array(
        'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
    );
    $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        exit(json_encode(array(
            'loginStatus' => true,
            'redirectUrl' => '/user-profile', // or else where you want to redirect
            'errorMsg' => ''
        )));
    } else {
        exit(json_encode(array(
            'loginStatus' => false,
            'redirectUrl' => false,
            'errorMsg' => 'Invalid username or Password'
        )));
    }
}
```

Js:- use the json data to show error message or rediect to User Profile page.

```
$('#login_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uname = $('#uname').val();
    var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
    if (uname == "" || upassword == "") {
        $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
    } else {
        $('#errmessage').html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/success/",
            data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
            success: function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data); // parse text to json object
                if (data.loginStatus) { // check if loginStatus is true
                    window.location.href = data.redirectUrl
                } else { // else show the error message
                    $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data.errorMsg);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#successmessage').fadeOut("slow");
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I understand on success you want to load view.

So when your ajax is called to a particular controller function, in return you have echo the view and in `$this->load->view('page_view',$data,TRUE)` pass true as the parameter.

Now in same page from where you are calling ajax have `div` element and replace the ajax success content.

This will load your view in that div.

As per your code, change to this below

```
if ($result == TRUE) {       
    echo $this->load->view('user_profile',TRUE);        
} else {
    $data = array(
    'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
    $this->load->view('user/login', $data);
}
```

Comment: but jquery and ajax is showing only   content on same login page

Comment: i want remove login page after login and load profile view

Comment: @user6171329 means you want to redirect to new or you want to load profile page on ajax ? If you redirect to profile page then on success you can redirect to controller of profile page

Comment: how to redirect profile page no need success message

Comment: success: function (data) {
                        $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#successmessage').fadeOut("slow");
                        }, 2000);
                    }

Comment: i want to remove that fade in settime function

Comment: `success: function (data) { $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data); location.reload(("<?php echo base url; ?>/controller/function_name");`

Comment: you are the great person you got my requirement thanks it's works for me

Answer (score 0):

working code

```
    $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uname = $('#uname').val();
        var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
        if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
        {
            $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
        } else {
            $('#errmessage').html("").hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/success/",
                data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data),
                    window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>/User_controller/profile");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

1. in your ajax script, set your datatype to script. you don't need to use success function here.

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?= base_url();?>User_controller/success/",
     data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
     datatype: 'script'
   );
   ```
2. in your method, use a flashdata for success message. then use redirect function to load a profile page.

   ```
   public function success() {
       $data = array(
          'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
          'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
       );

       $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
       if ($result == TRUE) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success Login');
         // you should have a route here that loads the profile page
         redirect('user/profile');
      } else {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
           // you should have a route here that loads the login page
           redirect('login');
      }
   ```

   }
3. in your login and profile page, add a div that will catch your flashdata, then you can add your setTimeout here.

`<div class="success"><?php $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="error"><?php $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
    </div>`

Comment: how will redirect works in PHP with echoing success message with ajax ?? Could you please explain ?

Comment: success: function (data) {
                        $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                        }, 2000);

Comment: @Rosiliza Rioja   i can redirect to my profile but  if login failed  what should i want to do in script

Comment: @user6171329 you can redirect it to login page. If you want to redirect using js, use `json` or `html` as datatype. then just `echo json_encode(false);` for incorrect login. then in success function, if the response data is false, you can show your error message.

Comment: i want to know script plz

Comment: @JiteshNK success message can be done using flash data of codeigniter

Comment: where do i add this code in controller ryt echo json_encode(false)

Comment: @SomnathJagtap sure